# overrule rowOnClick t:datatable

Tags: javascript, jsf, datatable

I have a t:datatable with rowOnClick event triggerd. This works, but I have in a column an icon and when you click the icon,a popup opens. But it also triggers the rowOnClick event. I don't want that, for that icon, I don't want the rowOnClick event to be triggerd.

Is it possible to override/overrule the rowOnClick event for certain columns in a datatable.

```
<t:dataTable rowClasses="row1,row2" id="typelist" value="#{vehicle.vehicleTypeList}" rowOnClick="selectType(#{vehicle_types.id},#{vehicle_types.reference})">

...
...
...

  <t:column id="carinformation" >
    <h:outputLink styleClass="listicons" value="#" onclick="popup=window.open('vehicle/detail.xhtml?vehicleid=#{vehicle_types.id}','vehciledetails','width=800,height=500,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');popup.focus();return false;" >
      <img src="images/information.gif" title="${msg.vehicle_information}"/>
    </h:outputLink>
  </t:column>   
</t:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM elements can be nested inside each other. And somehow, the handler of the parent works even if you click on it’s child.

The reason is event bubbling.

To stop this, add `event.stopPropagation();` to your image link's `onclick` so it would look like this:

```
<h:outputLink onclick="event.stopPropagation(); popup=window.open('vehicle/detail.xhtml?vehicleid=#{vehicle_types.id}','vehciledetails','width=800,height=500,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');popup.focus();return false;" >
  <img src="images/information.gif" title="${msg.vehicle_information}"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

**Read More:**

- [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)